# Possible ODataConventionModelBuilder bug when running EntitySet<> on a model with base class parameters hidden by new keyword

Tags: c#, odata

Consider a base class for the Microsoft example project object, WeatherForcast:

```
public enum CloudType { A = 1, B = 2 } 

public class WeatherForecastBase { public int CloudType { get; set; }} 

public class WeatherForecast : WeatherForecastBase { 

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Person WeatherPerson { get; set; }
    
    public virtual IList<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsCloudy { get; set; }
    
    public new CloudType CloudType { get; set; } }
```

The `CloudType` (int) property is hidden by the child class with a new property that also changes it's type (`CloudType` enum). Is there a way for `ODataConventionModelBuilder` to successfully build a model for WeatherForecast and ignore the base class version of `CloudType`? In my use case I get an error about the property must be a primitive type.

Comment: For anyone who needs help in the future, check out https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/1046. Use the Ignore() method to ignore both version of the property. This will remove the offending property from requests but it at least allows the model to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried  with Generic type which might be a workaroud for you:

```
 public class WeatherForecastBase<T>  {  public virtual T CloudType { get; set; } }

 public class WeatherForecast<T> : WeatherForecastBase<T>
 {

     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     public DateTime Date { get; set; }

     public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

     public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

     public string? Summary { get; set; }

     public bool IsCloudy { get; set; }

    
 }
```

in Program.cs:

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();    
modelBuilder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast<CloudType>>("WeatherForecast");
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
    options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents(
        "odata",
        modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately I am unable to update WeatherForecast.